# Can I sign in on another 3ds and still download games that I downloaded on another one

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Can I download games on a different 3ds that I bought on my other one by signing in on the second one or no?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it cannot be done.

> Your ID cannot be registered to more than one Nintendo 3DS system at one time. If you'd like to transfer your account to a new system, use the "Transfer title and data" procedure.

[image: Nintendo trying to explain that it's not possible to have the same NNID on multiple #3DS systems]

[Source](http://www.nintendo.com/3ds/nintendo-network-id/) (Nintendo itself).

Comment: @Solidstar Avoid +1 comments!